# Get value from array inside fetch result (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, fetch-api

I need to acess a **name** that is inside the array **area_set** that is inside a result from an API fetch. I try multiple ways but is says or that `map is undefined`or something else.

Here's the imagem of the json response:

[image]

Here's my code to ask for the json:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url + '/couch-model/1/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'JWT ' + (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token)
        }
    }).then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
        } else {
            throw Error(res.statusText);
        }
    }).then(json => {
        this.setState({
            model: json
        }, () => {
            console.log('model: ', json);
        });
    })
}
```

Here's the code inside render method:

```
 render() {

    const { model, isLoaded } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {

        return (
            <div id="LoadText">
                Estamos a preparar o seu sofá!
            </div>
        )

    } else {

        return (
                    <div id="Esquerda">
                        <h2>
                            {model.area_set.map(area =>
                                model.area.area_set[0].name
                            )}
                        </h2>

                        <h1>{model.name}</h1>
                        <p>Highly durable full-grain leather which is soft and has  a natural look and feel.</p>

                        <h3>Design</h3>
                        <h4>Hexagon</h4>
                    </div>
        );

    }

}
```

I'm really stuck in this, anybody can help?

Comment: shouldn't model.area_set[0].name do the trick?

Comment: It should, but doesn't, seems like react doesn't like the [0] @cdoshi `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: Why are you using map? map is used to create a new array and it seems you want to print the name. Also when you say map is undefined, that means model.area_set is undefined. Can you console.log model?

Comment: area_set is an array

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If area_set has multiple values, what do you want to print?

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro Could you please provide us the code that generates this json ?

Comment: the name inside array area_set @cdoshi

Comment: I edited the question @Weedoze

Comment: Make sure you are assigning `const model = this.state.model`  in your render method

Comment: model.area_set.map((area) => { console.log(area.name) })

Comment: I already had that, I didn't past on the question, sorry @kmukkamala

Comment: Again `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala

Comment: I think that you are rendering your component before having your model loaded. Please provide us a functional code snippet that reproduces the error

Comment: But I already can show the model.name

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` on line `Sofa.js:139` that says `{model.area_set.map(area =>`

Comment: can you please console.log the model variable before the return statement and paste the results here?

Comment: just when you enter render function log your state of component

Comment: that's on the image of the question, but there you go `area_set
:
Array(1)
0
:
{id: 1, couch_model: 1, name: "Area 1", json_3d_id: "1234", workmanship_set: Array(2), …}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
bibo_colors
:
null
brand
:
{id: 1, name: "LUSOGRAPH", image: "/media/filer_public/ac/0b/ac0ba5cb-4f00-4386-aa8b-984919abdf8d/logoluso.png", created_on: "2017-05-02T10:27:23.905454Z", updated_on: "2018-04-09T08:22:52.022891Z"}
category
:
null
code
:
"8ed96b9c"
couchmodelfile_set
:
(2) [{…}, {…}]
created_on
:
"2017-05-02T10:28:11.951052Z"`

Comment: Is that the json of the response, or the model variable though?

Comment: answer to `console.log(this.state.model);`

Comment: Have you seen this?@paqash

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala I still don't understand why this is happening

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro for our ease can you log this.state inside render and not the json you have posted in question

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EwfRRIg there you go, but it's the same as the question :/ @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getMeSomething = () => {
    if(this.state.model.area_set)
        return this.state.model.area_set.map(area => area.name)
}


render() {
    const { model, isLoaded } = this.state;
    if (!isLoaded) {
        return (
            <div id="LoadText">
                Estamos a preparar o seu sofá!
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
                    <div id="Esquerda">
                        <h2>
                            {this.getMeSomething()}
                        </h2>
                        <h1>{model.name}</h1>
                        <p>Highly durable full-grain leather which is soft and has  a natural look and feel.</p>
                        <h3>Design</h3>
                        <h4>Hexagon</h4>
                    </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Please try this way. In your case state doesnot have area_set defined in it so there is a high chance of not finding some instant. So it want you to handle that error

Comment: Line 117:  'model' is not defined & Line 144:  'getMeSomething' is not defined

Comment: I ahve written the function at top

Comment: replace model with this.state.model

Comment: I have editted. any more error in my code do mention

Comment: add return in the function. pls check the editted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
{model.area_set.map(area =>
    model.area.area_set[0].name
)}
```

This part looks weird. Try this instead:

```
{model.area_set.map(area =>
    area.name // This will yeild the name you are looking for once since the array is length = 1
)}
```